# Sitecore TDS Can not find site context

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, tds

I've been using TDS with Sitecore for a while but one of my sites has just started erroring with "Can not find site context" when trying to do a sync. Anyone know what would cause this?

The Site is Sitecore 8 and the version of TDS im using is 5.5 from Visual Studio 2015.

Stack trace is as follows:

```
Connection Test Pass: TDS service files are correctly installed.
Connection Test Message: Connector version local 5.5.0.19 and remote 5.5.0.19
Connection Test Pass: Access Guid check passed.
Found database master in the target Sitecore instance.
Connection Test Failure: Failed to complete test.
Exception System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Can not find site context. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Can not find site context.
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.LanguageFallbackDisabler..ctor()
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.TDSExecutionContext.Wrap[​](Func`1 func)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.TdsService.GetItem(String key, String sitecoreDatabase, String accessGuid, String itemIdOrPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.TdsService.GetItem(String key, String sitecoreDatabase, String accessGuid, String itemIdOrPath) (FaultException):

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoap.GetItem(GetItemRequest request)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoapClient.HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoap.GetItem(GetItemRequest request)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoapClient.GetItem(String key, String sitecoreDatabase, String accessGuid, String itemIdOrPath)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.ProjectTests.ConnectionTest.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0(String key)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Utils.Support.CallServiceWrapper[T](TdsServiceSoapClient client, SitecoreProjectNode project, Func`2 clientCall)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.ProjectTests.ConnectionTest.Execute()
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Dialogs.BuildTestDialog.RunTests()
Connection Test Finish: 2016-09-16 02:30:51
```

Comment: Is the website working fine otherwise? Do you have any exceptions in Sitecore logs?

Comment: Sites are otherwise working and no exceptions in the sitecore log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue had been caused from the path to the TDS service being added to the IgnoreUrlPrefix setting.

Comment: Where is this setting?  In Sitecore.config?  That's not the issue for me.. :*(

Comment: Web.config on Sitecore 8

Answer (score 3):

Please do the below mentioned steps to check the connectivity.

- Navigate to the Sitecore instance in a web browser and check that the
  **site is available**.
- Ensure that no firewalls are blocking access to the Sitecore
  instance.
- Navigate to the folder on disk that contains the Sitecore instance
  and check that the folder **_DEV** exists.
- Check that the **_DEV** folder contains the files **TdsService.asmx** and
  **web.config**.
- Check that the **bin** folder for the Sitecore instance contains the file
  **HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.dll**.

.

Comment: Tested all those things and they were all there. Tried deleting them and clicking the test button installed them all again, but still get the same error.

Comment: Did you ever find the source of this problem?  I have the same issue... all the above are set correctly, and the Test passes everything except the last one (Test Connection to Sitecore).

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused by using the wrong version of TDS.  I had 5.5.0.15 installed, but what I needed (and what all the TDS content was created with for this client) was 5.1.0.17

Installing the correct version resolved the problem.